# sqlite fixed choice and free choice

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to build up a database, that contains different process-times. So there is a column "time" in my maintable where i want to put in the time of a process. The time can either be a fixed choice of times, which remain the same e.g.
    08:00,12:00,18:00 or just 3 times a day (exact time is not really relevant)
    or
    06:00,20:00 or 2 times a day

or it can be a user-determined times (where the time is relevant!), e.g.
09:00, 10:30, 11:00

My question is, how would you put that into a sqlite database? It would be possible for the fixed times to use a distinct table and a foreign key in "time"-field of the main table. But how should i bring in the user-determined part then?

On the other hand i could use a distinct table that contains all times in an own row and connect all corresponding times using the foreign key of the main table. But that would not be really suitable for the fixed times.

In my opinion none of those solutiuons pleases me.

Comment: Why does the database need to know whether a time is a fixed time?

Comment: I thought it would be a good solution to keep the database small!? - That means you would just put every single time in a row and if the programm adds a new "3-times a day" entry to the database then the programm would split that up into the right times and save it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite stores integer data in 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, or 8 bytes depending on the magnitude of the value you are saving.  So if you wanted to use a key/value system, you could.  You could make a lookup table of times where a small, byte-sized numeric value represented whatever kind of time object you would like, for example:

```
Time (table)
index time type
1     08:00  fixed
2     12:00  fixed
3     18:00  fixed
4     06:00  fixed
5     20:00  fixed
6     09:00  free
7     10:30  free
```

then in process times (table):

```
timeIndex  processTime
3           24
7           22543
```

The values in the process times table would be stored as single bytes, assuming you had less than 256 different times, and as double bytes for times with index over 255.

SQlite's fast lookup ability could let you pull out the value for the time as you extract the value for processor time, and you would have a smaller database.